# How to mirror an image using array

Tags: c#

I need to mirror an image and display it like this:

[image]

To display like this:

[image]

This is my code so far, I have had no luck:

```
int Height = TransformedPic.GetLength(0);
int Width = TransformedPic.GetLength(1);

for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)//loop rows
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)//loop columns
    {
        TransformedPic[i, j] = TransformedPic[i, ((2 * Width) - (j + 1))];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look into bitmap/image methods to [flip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) the image1

Comment: @TaW pointing to MSDN with specific language selected is an interesting idea :)

Comment: I agree, sigh..But Microsoft/Google keeps sending me there; I hardly notice by now as I could set the language back to English; there ought to be a switch somewhere on ther page; it used to be at the top right.. Sometime it help changing the de-de in the url to en-en

Comment: I have added a line of code you would use if you wanted to do it at the bitmap pixel array level, but that is horribly inefficient..

Answer (score 5):

System.Drawing has [Image.RotateFlip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.rotateflip?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)
([Win32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/eb-en/library/windows/desktop/ms535401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) will do the job at lot faster and easier:

```
Bitmap bmp1 = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(bmp1.Width * 2, bmp1.Height);

using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2))
{
    G.DrawImage(bmp1, 0, 0);
    bmp1.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
    G.DrawImage(bmp1, bmp1.Width, 0);
    pictureBox2.Image = bmp2;
}
```

[image]

Instead you could use loops similar to yours and `Bitmap.GetPixel` and `Bitmap.SetPixel` but that would be really slow:

```
TransformedPic.SetPixel(Width - i, j, TransformedPic.GetPixel(i,j));
```

Going over one half of the width..

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it like this in one line:

```
picBox.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX)
```